# I can I install a 32 bit version of libsdl1.2debian on a 64 bit machine?

Tags: 32-bit, sdl

I'm trying to install a 32 bit version of libsdl1.2debian as a program I'm trying to run, Powder Toy, returns this when launched:

```
/home/kyle/golly/powder-89.2-lin32/powder: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I believe this means that the libSDL-1.2.so.0 is the 64 bit library. I tried to install the 32 bit version and get this:

```
kyle@GamingPC:~$ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian: i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package i386
```

I also tried looking for the package in Synaptic package manager with the search string "libsdl1.2" and it only returned the debug, dev and runtime libraries that I already have installed. No i386 libraries were found. Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to install 32bit package on 64bit machine

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

then install your any 32bit packages:(ex: with package that you want to install it)

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

Answer (score 2):

What ever package you want Ubuntu uses a system called Multiarch. Multiarch is a new approach to running programs compiled for one computer architecture on another, particular i386<->amd64

This is the package you want [libsdl1.2debian](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsdl1.2debian)

which does have multiarch support so you can run the following:

```
 sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```